# how I can run any .exe file through WebService

Tags: c#

how I can run any .exe file through WebService that I build ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process.Start("example.exe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to be able to send a exe file to your webservice and than execute that?

I would advice to following sequence.

1. Recieve the file and write it to a temporary directory.

   - Optionally scan the file with a anti-virus scanner. (Depending on the level of trust of your webservice)
   - Use Process.Start to start the temporary file and wait for it to stop running (perhaps supply a parameter to wait for exit or not)
   - Delete the temporary file.
   - Report back the result of the execution (if it's console application you could even report back the text printed by the application).

Comment: I wright this: 
      System.Diagnostics.Process H = new Process();
            H.StartInfo.FileName = @"d:\siw.exe";
            H.Start();
            H.WaitForExit();
   
but still not run

Comment: Process p = Process.Start(@"D:\siw.exe");
p.WaitForExit(); ?